# Capture lat long using gps without battery drain

Tags: android, geolocation

In my application I want to capture lat long using gps with particular interval. The interval should be 5 or 10 minute. 
My question is the GPS is enable only at the time of capture the location or it always enable the GPS to find the location updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should enable and disable gps using programming 
When you want to get location you should enable it other wise disable it.

Comment: Any idea how to enable and disable GPS through coding

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: I think a more accurate term for "enable/disable" is "getting a fix". You don't really turn the GPS on an off using code, you just stop getting a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use [LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29). Once you receive the location, post a Message to the Thread's Handler to fire off another `requestSingleUpdate()` request in 15 minutes.